# Sorting an array of month chronologicaly in swift

Tags: swift

Here is my array that i wan't to sort:

```
["Septembre", "Novembre", "Août", "Mars", "Décembre", "Octobre", "Juillet", "Avril", "Juin", "Février", "Janvier", "Mai"]
```

How can i sort this array?

Comment: How do you want to sort? Alphabetical or chronological?

Comment: Chronological i want it to be like (12, 11, 10, 09, 08, 07, 06, 05, 04, 03, 02, 01) but in String

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a Dictionary with key as the month name in String and value in int corresponding to the order in which the months come in the year. Then using this library http://www.dollarswift.org/#keys-keys you can

```
let monthsDict = ["feb": 1, "mar": 2, "jan": 0]
var months = $.keys(monthsDict)
months.sort {
    monthsDict[$0] < monthsDict[$1]
}
```

If you want it reversed you can just flip the equality operator

```
months.sort {
    monthsDict[$0] > monthsDict[$1]
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. You don't need the `$.keys` bit. You can sort the input array itself (make sure all values in there are actually in the dictionary).

Comment: Dollar is only available for ios 8 and i want my app to work on ios 7 too so i can't use $.keys(monthsDict)

Comment: @ClémentBisaillon After you install it as a submodule and dragging the project file into your project you can change the Targets > Dollar > Deployment Info to 7.0 for older iOS

Comment: It doesn't crashes at the compilation now but i get an error go see error 1 in my post