# Problems sorting an array of months swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

**Here is the problem:**

My API returns a list of monthly transactions, I have to grab that result, divide it into sections to populate a tableView where each section is a month with its respective transactions.

**Here is the Code**

```
var sectionTest = Dictionary<String, Array<TableSections>>()
var sortedSections: [String] = []

for entry in entries {
    if entry.type != "S" {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: entry.date) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
            dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR") as Locale!
            let sectionMonth = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

            if self.sectionTest.index(forKey: sectionMonth) == nil {
                self.sectionTest[sectionMonth] = [TableSections(month: sectionMonth, description: entry.description, value: entry.value, date: entry.date, type: entry.type)]
            } else {
                self.sectionTest[sectionMonth]?.append(TableSections(month: sectionMonth, description: entry.description, value: entry.value, date: entry.date, type: entry.type))
            }

            self.sortedSections = self.sectionTest.keys.sorted(by: >)
```

**Here is where I'm stuck**

self.sortedSections returns an array sorted by alphabetical order, in this case if I request for the last 60 days of transactions it will return an array with:

```
print(sortedSections)
["november", "january", "december"]
```

Comment: look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052868/sorting-an-array-of-month-chronologicaly-in-swift

Comment: `Date` conforms to `Comparable` protocol. If you need to sort your objects all you need is to sort it using the actual dates

Comment: Note that since Swift 3 you are supposed to use `Locale` initializers  instead of `NSLocale`

Comment: @LeoDabus I really dont see how, I've been working at this for 2 days and still cant fix it, can you give me a tip or something?

Comment: If you don't post the  JSON you are receiving and your data structure we can't really help.

Comment: Btw I suggest updating your Xcode to the latest version and starting to take a look at the Codable protocol

Comment: I can only show the model from the swagger example, the actual JSON is protected under a contract and cannot be posted anywhere on the internet.

Comment: upgrade to what dude? X code is the latest and the language was set by the client, we dont have the resources or the need to upgrade to swift 4... so theres no need to upgrade anything. if you can't actually help..I think ur just wasting ur time here than...

Comment: Swift 4 just go to the AppStore and download the latest Xcode version.

Comment: I wonder how can it be printing ["november", "january", "december"] if you are setting your locale to Portuguese Brazil

Comment: I translated so it would be easier for people to undestand...

Comment: I already told you how to solve your issue. Just sort it using the date itself. Just create a structure that contains only the dates and use the date formatter only when displaying it.

Comment: This (well, very similar) was asked and answered just a couple hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322519/how-to-sort-month-name-in-ascending-or-descending-order-using-nssortdescriptor-i